# Why context.Wait in StartAsync didn't stop the dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm sure is stupid question, but I will more stupid if I didn't ask
I have the following code

```
    [Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("RootDialog !");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // calculate something for us to return
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        // return our reply to the user
        await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

I understant the statement context.Wait is use to wait the next message of the user.
But if I launch my RootDialog my statement 
            await context.PostAsync("RootDialog !");
Is executed and just after my statement 
await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
is exectuted too.

Why ?

Why I didn't a pause in my programm with the statement
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
in the StartAsync function like I have in the MessageReceivedAsync function ?

Comment: What version of BotBuilder are u using? How are you creating/launching the `RootDialog`?. BTW, if this dialog is launched with Conversation.SendAsync() and happens after a message, then it's ok the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I use the last version I thinks. 3.8. Yes a usé Conversation.SendAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some description of IDialogContext.Wait in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs#implementation-details

> The StartAsync method calls IDialogContext.Wait with the continuation
>   delegate to specify the method that should be called when a new
>   message is received (MessageReceivedAsync).

A bot built using the BotBuilder SDK is restful and stateless, in the sense that the server itself doesn't track or store session information.  "context.Wait(method)" doesn't mean "freeze the code here", but rather: resume at this method in the dialog the next time a message comes from the user.  The method to call next is actually serialized with the dialog and stored in the `State Service` (see here: [Manage state data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state) The last context.Wait(methodname) will be called the next time the user sends a message in the context of the same conversation.

An example might be useful:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // calculate something for us to return
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        // return our reply to the user
        await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");


        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync2);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync2(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Second MessageReceived");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

The code above will switch back and forth between MessageReceivedAsync and MessageReceivedAsync2 for every message sent by the user.

[image]